# Pandas dataframe check if date in a column is less than custom days?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime

df has two columns name and date(date in any format - string format/datetime format).
Currently its in string format.

df

```
            name      date              

    0       john     2019-08-24 05:30:30

    1       jude     2020-03-03 21:15:03
```

if `date` is less than 10 days from current time, add a new column(output) false to it and true otherwise.

Expected Output

```
          name      date                 output  

  0       john     2019-08-24 05:30:30    False

  1       jude     2020-03-03 21:15:03    True
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with corrent datetime subtracted by 10 days and current datetime:

```
#if necessary
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

now = pd.to_datetime('now')
df['output'] = df['date'].between(now - pd.Timedelta(10, 'd'), now)
```

It working same like chained mask by bitwise `AND` for `greater or equal` - [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) and `less or equal` - [`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html):

```
df['output'] = df['date'].ge(now - pd.Timedelta(10, 'd')) & df['date'].le(now)
#alternative
#df['output'] = (df['date'] >= now - pd.Timedelta(10, 'd')) & (df['date'] <= now)

print (df)
   name                date  output
0  john 2019-08-24 05:30:30   False
1  jude 2020-03-03 21:15:03    True
```

If want another combinations is possible use [`Series.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html),
[`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html),
[`Series.le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.le.html),
[`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html).

If want omit times and working only with dates add [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) and [`Timestamp.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.date.html):

```
#if necessary
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

now = pd.to_datetime('now').date()
df['output'] = df['date'].dt.date.between(now - pd.Timedelta(10, 'd'), now)
print (df)
   name                date  output
0  john 2019-08-24 05:30:30   False
1  jude 2020-03-03 21:15:03    True
```